# Is it possible to use login status control without the membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I have a login page and i have  not used the login controls in asp.net ... Can i still use the login status control? If yes how do i use it plzz help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom MembershipProvider. and the user is by some way is logged in then they login status control is evidently usable.

check this example

[ASP.NET Login Control with custom membership provider database](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-membership-provider-database.html)